# copying std::vector<unsigned char> to void * buffer using memcpy

Tags: c++, hex, memcpy

I have a custom function which copying values to the buffer

```
void foo(void *buffer, std::initializer_list<unsigned char> l) {
   memcpy(buffer, l.begin(), l.size());
}
```

Initializer list argument takes hexadecimal value as paramater. However I want to change it to string representation like instead of passing parameter as {0x01, 0x02, 0x04}, I would like to pass it as "0x01 0x02 0x04".

I changed `std::initializer_list<unsigned char>` to std::vector. But I got invalid casting error from `vector` to `void *`.

```
void foo(void *buffer, std::vector<unsigned char> l) {
   memcpy(buffer, reinterpret_cast<void *>(l.begin()), l.size());
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `std::vector` based code you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector::begin` returns an iterator *not* a pointer to the first element.  Try...

```
void foo(void *buffer, std::vector<unsigned char> l)
{
    memcpy(buffer, l.data(), l.size());
}
```

Better still, if the vector is large then you might want to consider passing by const reference rather than by value...

```
void foo(void *buffer, const std::vector<unsigned char> &l)
{
    memcpy(buffer, l.data(), l.size());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although iterators returned from .begin() or .end() might work like pointers,
but that does not guarantee that they are really alias of real pointers.
Think of iterators from `std::map` for example.
They should contain more information rather than just a pointer since they iterate through binary tree.

It makes sense to think of iterator from continuous container as pointer,
maybe they really are, but remember the C++ standard does not guarantee it.

Anyways, here's my solution.

```cpp
void foo(void *buffer, std::vector<unsigned char> l) {
   memcpy(buffer, &*l.begin(), l.size());
}
```

Looks weird but does the job correctly.
The other answer's solution looks more elegant tho :)

Comment: In the realm of nitpicking, `&*l.begin()` arguably should be `std::addressof(*l.begin())`, in case someone has overloaded the unary `&` operator for their type. That's not something I'd worry about in real-world code, but you need to be alert to the possibility. +1.

Comment: As for "looks more elegant", this answer can be generalized to be much more elegant: `template <class Iter> void foo(void *buffer, Iter first, Iter last) { memcpy(buffer, &*first, &*last); }` That way it works with **any** range, not just a range that's managed by a vector.

Answer (score 1):

If using `memcpy` isn't an absolute requirement, there's a higher-level approach:

```
std::uninitialized_copy(l.begin(), l.end(), (unsigned char*)buffer);
```

But I'd make it more general:

```
template <class Iter>
void foo(void *buffer, Iter first, Iter last) {
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type *ptr;
    std::uninitialized_copy(first, last, static_cast<ptr>(buffer));
}
```

This one works with any range and any type.